# why am I getting warning/error when working with tensorflow (use functional API and not implemented error)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to follow this tutorial but with my data: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns

All of my data is numerical values.

when I ran this part of code:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=test_ds, epochs=100, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

I am getting this type of warning for all of the parameters:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Layers in a Sequential model should only have a single input tensor, but we receive a <class 'dict'> input: {'age': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_8:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>,
```

I am getting this warning twice for each variable!

and then I am getting this error:

```
UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
 [[node sequential_7/dense_features_7/calprotectin/Cast (defined at <ipython-input-103-5689ba5df442>:5) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4860]
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

## Edit1

I tried to mimic my code and error using sample data and I came up with this code.

The code doesn't generate an error but generates a warning. so the problem is with the data that I am reading. What can go wrong with the input data that generate such an error?

( it is a jupyter code, how can I post it here?) :

```
%reset
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow import feature_column
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

RANDOM_SEED = 42

data=pd.DataFrame()
data['sex']=[1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1]
data['age']=[10,11,13,45,67,34,23,62,82,78]
data['bmi']=[22.5,28.8,19,23.3,26,18.4,27.5,29,30.3,25.9]
data['smoker']=[1,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,1,1]
data['lab1']=[144,124,126,146,130,124,171,147,131,138]
data['lab2']=[71,82,75,65,56,89,55,74,78,69]
data['result']=[1,2,2,4,3,2,1,3,2,4]

feature_columns = []
for header in ['sex','age', 'bmi','smoker', 'lab1', 'lab2']:
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(header))

def create_dataset(dataframe, batch_size=32):
    dataframe = dataframe.copy()
    labels = dataframe.pop('result')
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels)) \
      .shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe)) \
      .batch(batch_size)

train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)
train_ds = create_dataset(train)
test_ds = create_dataset(test)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns=feature_columns),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.1),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=test_ds, epochs=100, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

when I run the above code, I am getting this warning:

```
Epoch 1/100
WARNING:tensorflow:Layers in a Sequential model should only have a single input tensor, but we receive a <class 'dict'> input: {'sex': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_4:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'age': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'bmi': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_1:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'smoker': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_5:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'lab1': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_2:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'lab2': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_3:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>}
Consider rewriting this model with the Functional API.
WARNING:tensorflow:Layers in a Sequential model should only have a single input tensor, but we receive a <class 'dict'> input: {'sex': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_4:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'age': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'bmi': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_1:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'smoker': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_5:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'lab1': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_2:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'lab2': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_3:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>}
Consider rewriting this model with the Functional API.
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: -22.8739 - accuracy: 0.2500WARNING:tensorflow:Layers in a Sequential model should only have a single input tensor, but we receive a <class 'dict'> input: {'sex': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_4:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'age': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'bmi': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_1:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float64>, 'smoker': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_5:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'lab1': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_2:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>, 'lab2': <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_3:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>}
Consider rewriting this model with the Functional API.
```

When model fit finished, the accuracy is zero. I know that the data is not valid, bit having an accuracy of zero is also not expected.

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example so we can reproduce your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you have no improvement when training the model because you using `BinaryCrossentropy` loss for multi-labels, deal this error wrt following two case

1. For binary classification:

   Let, e.g `data['result']=[1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]` and using `loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)`
2. For multiclass classification:

   Using `loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)`, and modify the output layer of model so it outputs shape match the number of labels, e.g `tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)` when you have 5 classes

That `WARNING` from `tf.keras.models.Sequential()` is simply telling you what it expect from layer within it in order for it to work properly, if you don't using `tf.keras.models.Sequential()` then `WARNING` will disappear, e.g define model using:

```
inputs = {}
for header in ['sex','age', 'bmi','smoker', 'lab1', 'lab2']:
    inputs[header] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=header) 
x = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns=feature_columns)(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.1)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
```

The reason you get that error of `Cast string to float` probably due to you try to convert all the columns to `numeric column` like you did in that example code you post (i.e maybe better to convert `sex` columns to `categorical columns`)

Answer (score 1):

To fix this warning, you have 2 ways:

1] Apply features layer in the input when you call for fit method.
i.e. instead of:

```
model3.fit(x=train_dict, y=train_labels, validation_data=(valid_dict,valid_labels), epochs=epochs_, verbose=verbose_)
```

use

```
model3.fit(x=feature_layer_3(train_dict), y=train_labels, validation_data=(feature_layer_3(valid_dict),valid_labels), epochs=epochs_, verbose=verbose_)
```

you could check this detailed example (3rd Model)
https://www.kaggle.com/abidou/features-bucketing

2] Use Functional API as in 6th model in previous link